# How do I name my XML header 'header list-id: "inventory"' in a C# model?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

The first step of a project I'm working on is to create an `XML` file from a list of records. It used to be written in `java`, but I'm migrating it to `C#`. The way they did it in java was by explicitly writing out each and every line, and I'm trying to incorporate a way to do it programmatically so the values can be changed during later steps of deployment.

The file that I have to replicate has a header name of **header list-id: "inventory"**.

I have it just writing 'header' fine, but I can't figure out how to include the rest.

```
    [Serializable()]
    [DesignerCategory("code")]
    [XmlType(AnonymousType = false, Namespace = "http://www.demandware.com/xml/impex/inventory/2007-05-31")]
    [XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://www.demandware.com/xml/impex/inventory/2007-05-31", IsNullable = false)]
    public partial class inventory
    {

        private inventoryInventorylist inventorylistField;

        [XmlElement("inventory-list")]
        public inventoryInventorylist inventorylist
        {
            get
            {
                return inventorylistField;
            }
            set
            {
                inventorylistField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    [Serializable()]
    [DesignerCategory("code")]
    [XmlType(AnonymousType = true, TypeName = "inventory-list")]
    public partial class inventoryInventorylist
    {
        public inventoryInventorylistHeader header;

        private inventoryInventorylistHeader headerField
        {
            get
            {
                return header;
            }
            set
            {
                header = value;
            }
        }
    }

    [Serializable()]
    [DesignerCategory("code")]
    [XmlType(AnonymousType = false, TypeName = "header")]
    public partial class inventoryInventorylistHeader 
    {

        [XmlElement("default-instock")]
        public bool defaultinstock
        {
            get
            {
                return defaultinstockField;
            }
            set
            {
                defaultinstockField = false;
            }
        }

        [XmlElement("description")]
        public string description
        {
            get
            {
                return descriptionField;
            }
            set
            {
                descriptionField = "Inventory";
            }
        }

        [XmlElement("use-bundle-inventory-only")]
        public bool usebundleinventoryonly
        {
            get
            {
                return usebundleinventoryonlyField;
            }
            set
            {
                usebundleinventoryonlyField = false;
            }
        }

        [XmlElement("on-order")]
        public bool onorder
        {
            get
            {
                return onorderField;
            }
            set
            {
                onorderField = false;
            }
        }
}
```

Creation:

```
 var inventory = new inventory()
 {
     inventorylist = new inventoryInventorylist()
     {
          header = new inventoryInventorylistHeader()
          {
              defaultinstock = false,
              description = "Inventory",
              usebundleinventoryonly = false,
              onorder = false
          }
     }
 }
```

Returns this:

```
<inventory xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.demandware.com/xml/impex/inventory/2007-05-31">
  <inventory-list>
    <header>
      <default-instock>false</default-instock>
      <description>Inventory</description>
      <use-bundle-inventory-only>false</use-bundle-inventory-only>
      <on-order>false</on-order>
    </header>
```

I want it to return this:

```
<inventory xmlns="http://www.demandware.com/xml/impex/inventory/2007-05-31">
  <inventory-list>
    <header list-id="inventory">
      <default-instock>false</default-instock>
      <description>Inventory</description>
      <use-bundle-inventory-only>false</use-bundle-inventory-only>
      <on-order>false</on-order>
    </header>
```

If I write this in the model:

```
public partial class inventoryInventorylist
    {
        [XmlElement("header list-id:\"inventory\"")]
        public inventoryInventorylistHeader header;
```

Then it gets changed to this:

```
<inventory-list>
    <header_x0020_list-id_x003A__x0022_inventory_x0022_>
      <default-instock>false</default-instock>
      <description>Inventory</description>
      <use-bundle-inventory-only>false</use-bundle-inventory-only>
      <on-order>false</on-order>
    </header_x0020_list-id_x003A__x0022_inventory_x0022_>
```

How would I force it to display the desired text when I serialize the model?

Comment: When you use [XmlElement()] is creates one xml tag.  To create two tags for one c# class property you must has an array or list object :public inventoryInventorylistHeader[] header;  The precede with [XmlArray("inventory")] and [XmlArrayItem("inventory-list"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a XmlAttribute attribute for that.
If you add

```
[XmlAttribute("list-id")]
public string listid
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

to your inventoryInventorylistHeader class, you will get the xml as described in your question.

What i usually do is take the xml and generate an xsd using visual studio.
Then I will open a vs developer command prompt and use xsd.exe to generate the classes. These can then be slightly refactored to look nicer in code.

Comment: Ah, thanks! That worked. Your method sounds better than what I did, which was import the xsd that the file is supposed to adhere to. Thank you again.